# Import CSV file into Excel understanding the date importing issue

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have received help on this before, but I clearly don't understand the date import. The file I want to import has data in Columns A to D. I Only want to import A to C. This part I get right but the issues are the dates. Currently in the CSV file it is in the format of YYYYMMDD I need it to convert it to dd/mm/yyyy. My regional settings are in that format.

When I run the code the dates are totally botched instead for example 04 December 2023 which needs to be 04/12/2023 it changes the date to 12/04/2023 it reads as 12 April 2023.

Here is my attempt:

```
Private Sub ImprtBtnABSA_Click()
    Dim vFile, arIn, arOut()
    Dim wbCSV As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, s As String
    Dim t0 As Single

    'Select a text file through the file dialog.
    'Get the path and file name of the selected file to the variable.
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("ExcelFile *.txt,*.txt;*.csv", _
        Title:="Select CSV file", MultiSelect:=False)

    'If you don't select a file, exit sub.
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    t0 = Timer

    'The selected text file is imported into an Excel file. format:2 is csv, format:1 is tab
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=vFile, Format:=2, ReadOnly:=True)

    'Bring all the contents of the sheet into an array
    'and close the text file
    With wbCSV.Sheets(1)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub ' If last row is less than 2, exit sub
        ' Exclude the last row by adjusting the range
        arIn = .Range("A2:C" & lastRow).Value
        
        wbCSV.Close
    End With
    
    'built output array from input array
    ReDim Preserve arOut(1 To UBound(arIn), 1 To 3)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arIn, 1)
        ' Adjust column numbers as needed
        s = Trim(arIn(i, 2))
        ' Remove text within parentheses including brackets
        s = RemoveTextInParentheses(s)
        ' Assuming the date is in the format YYYYMMDD
        arOut(i, 1) = Format(DateSerial(Left(arIn(i, 1), 4), Mid(arIn(i, 1), 5, 2), Right(arIn(i, 1), 2)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        arOut(i, 2) = s ' Trimmed and without text within parentheses
        arOut(i, 3) = arIn(i, 3) ' Column C
    Next

    'write output array to sheet2
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("A1:C1") = Array("Date", "Description", "Amount")
        .Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        .Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "General"
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arOut), 3).Value = arOut
        .Columns("A:C").AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to xif it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the TextToColumns to handle the dates.

Start with removing the line:

```
    ' Assuming the date is in the format YYYYMMDD
    arOut(i, 1) = Format(DateSerial(Left(arIn(i, 1), 4), Mid(arIn(i, 1), 5, 2), Right(arIn(i, 1), 2)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

to keep the format as is.

Then you need to output your data on the sheet, do the text to columns and then change the date format:

```
'write output array to sheet2
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    .UsedRange.Clear
    .Range("A1:C1") = Array("Date", "Description", "Amount")
    .Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
    .Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "General"
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arOut), 3).Value = arOut
    .Columns("A:C").AutoFit
End With 

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 5), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Now you should be able to set the format of the cells as you like

[image]

Comment: This worked thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between a Date and a String that looks like a Date.
Dates are stored as numbers internally. Those numbers have no format, they simply store the number of days since a magic date (1.1.1900). You then can set the number format of a cell to display this number as a date - in various forms. Changing the number format doesn't change the date itself, so displaying `Mar 31, 2023` or `31.03.2023` or `Freitag, 3. März 2023` will all be stored as the same value. You can even format the cell as number and will see this value (45016).

Strings are a sequence of characters and *may* look like a date, but they are not.

You are writing the date as String into Excel, not as Dates. Your statement

```
arOut(i, 1) = Format(DateSerial(Left(arIn(i, 1), 4), Mid(arIn(i, 1), 5, 2), Right(arIn(i, 1), 2)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

will first create a real Date using the `DateSerial`-function. But then you convert it back into a string using the `Format`-function. So Excel will not know that you have a date here. Setting number formats to a cell that contains a string will have no effect, you can't format strings.

Remove the `Format`-function from the statement should do the trick:

```
arOut(i, 1) = DateSerial(Left(arIn(i, 1), 4), Mid(arIn(i, 1), 5, 2), Right(arIn(i, 1), 2))
```

Now real dates are written into the sheet and you can use the number format to display the date as you want.

Comment: My question though does Excel only understand it as date if the date format in the CSV file matches the regional format settings or the format in the cell? My idea was to try and get the string to match my regional format of dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Dates in CSV files are always problematic - you force Excel (or whatever process you use to read the data) to guess that a) the field is a Date and b) the exact format of that date. And guessing in IT is always a bad idea. So if you know the format (in your case YYYYMMDD) and convert it by code, you are on the save side.